# Multiple grpc streaming server connection to JS client via envoy not working properly

Tags: javascript, grpc, envoyproxy, grpc-web

We need to connect three grpc streaming servers simultaneously. In this scenario, each server has two streaming methods, totaling six connections. The streaming continues for three to five minutes after the browser throws an error.

Envoy config -->

```
yaml

static_resources:
  listeners:
    - name: listener_0
      address:
        socket_address:
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: 7804
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
                codec_type: auto
                stat_prefix: ingress_http
                stream_idle_timeout: 0s
                route_config:
                  name: local_route
                  virtual_hosts:
                    - name: local_service_1
                      domains:
                        - "*"
                      routes:
                        - match:
                            prefix: /
                          route:
                            cluster: service_1
                            timeout: 0s
                            max_stream_duration:
                              grpc_timeout_header_max: 0s
                      cors:
                        allow_origin_string_match:
                          - prefix: "*"
                        allow_methods: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS
                        allow_headers: keep-alive,user-agent,cache-control,content-type,content-transfer-encoding,custom-header-1,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout
                        max_age: "1728000"
                        expose_headers: custom-header-1,grpc-status,grpc-message
                http_filters:
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.grpc_web
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.grpc_web.v3.GrpcWeb
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.cors
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.cors.v3.Cors
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.router
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
    - name: listener_1
      address:
        socket_address:
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: 7802
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
                codec_type: auto
                stat_prefix: ingress_http_2
                stream_idle_timeout: 0s
                route_config:
                  name: local_route_2
                  virtual_hosts:
                    - name: local_service_2
                      domains:
                        - "*"
                      routes:
                        - match:
                            prefix: /
                          route:
                            cluster: service_2
                            timeout: 0s
                            max_stream_duration:
                              grpc_timeout_header_max: 0s
                      cors:
                        allow_origin_string_match:
                          - prefix: "*"
                        allow_methods: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS
                        allow_headers: keep-alive,user-agent,cache-control,content-type,content-transfer-encoding,custom-header-1,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout
                        max_age: "1728000"
                        expose_headers: custom-header-1,grpc-status,grpc-message
                http_filters:
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.grpc_web
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.grpc_web.v3.GrpcWeb
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.cors
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.cors.v3.Cors
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.router
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
    - name: listener_2
      address:
        socket_address:
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: 7803
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
                codec_type: auto
                stat_prefix: ingress_http
                stream_idle_timeout: 0s
                route_config:
                  name: local_route
                  virtual_hosts:
                    - name: local_service_3
                      domains:
                        - "*"
                      routes:
                        - match:
                            prefix: /
                          route:
                            cluster: service_3
                            timeout: 0s
                            max_stream_duration:
                              grpc_timeout_header_max: 0s
                      cors:
                        allow_origin_string_match:
                          - prefix: "*"
                        allow_methods: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS
                        allow_headers: keep-alive,user-agent,cache-control,content-type,content-transfer-encoding,custom-header-1,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout
                        max_age: "1728000"
                        expose_headers: custom-header-1,grpc-status,grpc-message
                http_filters:
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.grpc_web
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.grpc_web.v3.GrpcWeb
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.cors
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.cors.v3.Cors
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.router
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
  clusters:
    - name: service_1
      connect_timeout: 25s
      type: logical_dns
      http2_protocol_options: {}
      lb_policy: round_robin
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: cluster_0
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: ip
                      port_value: 7804
    - name: service_2
      connect_timeout: 25s
      type: logical_dns
      http2_protocol_options: {}
      lb_policy: round_robin
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: cluster_0
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: ip
                      port_value: 7802
    - name: service_3
      connect_timeout: 25s
      type: logical_dns
      http2_protocol_options: {}
      lb_policy: round_robin
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: cluster_0
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: ip
                      port_value: 7801
```

---

Do we require any envoy configuration changes?  Or are there any other choices, like using WebSocket for communications between clients and envoys?

We attempted to connect numerous grpc streaming servers from a JS client using grpc-web via envoy and HTTP2; but, the connection only lasted for five minutes until it crashed the browser.